# How do I allow my GCP Load Balancer to access a Bucket in another project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, load-balancing

I am trying to configure my load balancer to point to a bucket in another project. The projects are

- my-infra
- my-dev

I create the bucket in my-infra and then I add the default App Engine service account to it as a user. The bucket is also public since it will be housing our static site data. However, when I try to create a load balancer in my-dev and point it at the bucket it fails saying...

> Operation type [update] failed with message “The Cloud Storage bucket ‘my-bucket’ is not owned by the current project ‘my-dev’.”

This is true it isn't owned by that project because it is in infra and it will be referenced by multiple projects. How do I point my load balancer at the bucket in the other project?

I see there are some ACL commands but since I am using IAM I don't think the ACL commands will work.

Answer (score 5):

There is a feature called [`Cross-Project Service Referencing`](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/networking/cloud-load-balancing-gets-cross-project-service-referencing) but at the moment, this is **not supported** by Global external HTTP(S) Load Balancers. And Cloud Storage [only supports](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/features#backends:%7E:text=Cloud%20Storage%20in%20backend%20buckets) Global external HTTP(S) load balancers which means that what you are currently trying to achieve isn't feasible at the moment.

A feature request has been raised for the set up that you are going for. To keep track of the status/progress of this feature request, please follow this [feature request link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117925385) and click the `+1` and the `star` button to get notified about its update(s).